# Error is Keras when training with MirroredStrategy

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

When I use MirroredStrategy to train my model in Keras I get an error which I do not receive when not using MirroredStrategy. Here is some sample code

```
# Create a MirroredStrategy.
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
print('Number of devices: {}'.format(strategy.num_replicas_in_sync))

# Open a strategy scope.
with strategy.scope():
  # Everything that creates variables should be under the strategy scope.
  # In general this is only model construction & `compile()`.
  model = Model(...)
  model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_absolute_error'], loss_weights = [l1,l2])

# Train the model on all available devices.
model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=val_dataset, ...)

# Test the model on all available devices.
model.evaluate(test_dataset)
```

The error that I receive is `TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Equal' Op has type variant that does not match type float32 of argument 'x'.`

I believe this error has to do with the loss function. It is important to note that I have 1 input and 2 outputs for my model.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that upgrading tensorflow 2.0 fixed the issue. Currently using the latest release.